# Qt webkit programming, what's the corresponding Qt data types to Javascript data types?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am currently working on this topic: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html

I have a C++ class that maps a Javascript object and I want my C++ function to return any Javascript data types, such as object, array, string, number etc.

What's the corresponding Qt data types to JS data types?

e.g. (I don't know if this mapping is correct)

```
Javascript data type                 Qt data type

string                                QString
array                                 QList, QVariantList
.....
```

I just want to know how the data type maps to each other.

Comment: I'm not sure how much attention did you pay to the documentation you cited, but all you need is there: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit-bridge.html#data-types.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding. I've tried several qt types, such as QObjectList and QVariantList, but seemed the javascript engine couldn't recognize them

Answer (score 1):

You might find some clues here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscriptvalue.html

Comment: As of Qt 4.7, QtScript doesn't have anything to do with the JavaScript <-> Qt bridge that's available in QtWebKit.

Comment: True, but it is still based on the same idea and core tech, which is QVariant.